# PyCharm - Any way to configure secondary / minor language for a file

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I wish to configure secondary / minor language for some file.

For example: `test.html.j2`, I wish that support Jinja2 as primary language but also HTML for tag completion for example.

For ensile for example, I want to have `test.yml.j2` for Jinja2 support and YAML indentation.

Comment: Does PyCharm has something like Template Data Language (like PhpStorm has: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.2/template-data-languages-settings.html) where you can specify other language than default one. P.S. PhpStorm detects most of double extensions automatically (e.g. `file.js.php` will be JavaScript file with PHP; `file.xml.twig` will be XML with Twig) -- wonder if similar thing can be done in PyCharm...

Comment: I think this ticket describes the same what you are asking here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
I find a way to do want I want.

- Step 1: I set in Pycharm a language template

[image: Set language template]

- Step 2: I mark my directory as template directory

[image]

- Step 3: I set yml.j2 as extension for yaml

[image]

**And now It's working !**